# Problem with updating data value of an object inside another object; value isn't updating

Tags: c++, class

I have 2 classes, a Party class and an Inventory class. The party class has an inventory object (called party_inventory_) inside it, and the Inventory class has a gold data member (called gold_, and it is default set to 100).

The party class has a getInventory function:

```
Inventory Party::getInventory() {
    return party_inventory_; 
}
```

And Inventory has a get gold and add gold functions:

```
int Inventory::getGold() {
    return gold_;
}

//cout statement so I could check if it was even entering the function
void Inventory::addGold(int gold) {
    cout << "Entered addGold func. gold_: " << gold_ << " gold: " << gold << endl;
    gold_ += gold;
    return;
}
```

So I create a party object called party1. I then call `party1.getInventory().getGold()` which returns 100, as expected. Then I do `party1.getInventory().addGold(50)`. Then I do `party1.getInventory(),getGold()` again, but it still returns 100, not 150.

I asked ChatGPT (I know I know) and it said my current function is only pass by copy, so it doesn't actually update the value of gold in party_inventory, it only makes a copy of party_inventory and adds gold to that. So to fix it I need to make it pass by reference with a pointer(?) by changing the return type of getInventory() to Inventory& (with a & at the end)

I tried that and it did in fact work. But my problem is we haven't covered pointers (or whatever that is) in my cs course, so I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use that (I also just have no clue what I'm actually doing with it). Is there any way to fix this without using a pointer? Any help is appreciated

Comment: `getInventory` returns a copy. You probably want to return a reference. The problen with that is you're exposing the internals of your class. You might instead want to add `getGold` and `setGold` to the `Party` interface. For now you could just pass those through, but if you wanted to change how the inventory is kept you could change those two functions instead of having to change everywhere that `getInventory` was used.

Comment: *'I tried that and it didn't work'*. It sounds like ChatGPT was right, and what you tried should have worked. Since it didn't the only way to progress would be for you to post the code you tried. It's much easier to post code than describe code.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Depending on how much functionality the `Party` actually incorporates grouping via sub-objects might not be the worst idea – and maybe we have a common party inventory and separate personal inventories for each character, then we could possibly re-use the `Inventory` for both... But yes, of course, reference necessary for...

Comment: @Wofster Side note: Would your game allow a negative amount of gold (i.e. depts) in your inventory? If not and you're sure about never incorporating that (or plan to keep depts in separate variables as you might to need to store how much the party is in dept to which persons) then I'd rather use `unsigned int` to express this fact in code as well.

Comment: Actually you need to clearly differenciate: What is proposed here is a *reference* (in C++wording). A *pointer* is `Inventory*`, and to access pointer members you need to use `pointer->member` syntax (or explicitly dereference – which the arrow syntax actually is syntactic sugar for: `(*pointer).member`). In respect to being allowed to use or not: I'd simply ask the teacher/professor...

Comment: If you are indeed not allowed to use pointers/references and want to keep code changes as minimal as possible (you might be allowed to use them later on then) you could add a function to copy the modified inventory back into the party object. I'd consider this, though, at best as a workaround and keep it as the last resort.